# How to avoid `.clang-format` content duplication across multiple repositories?

Tags: clang-format

We're using clang-format in a git repository and we'd like to have one central `.clang-format` file that we maintain for all of our C/C++/proto code. We use submodules to share a "common" repository across multiple top-level "project" repositories. We would like each repository to have the same formatting rules, and for those rules to be centralized in the "common" repository.

In the following ASCII art, `project1` is a leaf repository, and `common` is the shared submodule:

```
/project1 <-- leaf repository
  .clang-format
  /external
    /common <-- submodule repository
      .clang-format
```

At best, the two `.clang-format` files are copies. At worse, they diverge.

We don't want to change `/project1/.clang-format` to be a symlink, because we support Windows.

We saw the `-style=file:<format_file_path>` flag from the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#configuring-style-with-clang-format), and that seems like it would work for a formatting tool. But, that solution is challenging for editors that don't have "project files" that can be checked in at the root of `/project1`- we would also like to support integrated `clang-format` LSP support in our editors, and that requires either a local `.clang-format` file being found, or a global editor being configured with very project-specific path details.

If `clang-format` supported configuration file references, then `/project1/.clang-format` could be a tiny file that just says "Use the contents of `./external/common/.clang-format`" but that functionality doesn't appear to exist.

How can we avoid the duplication of `.clang-format` files given these constraints?